# Interpolation of NaN values using akima in python

Tags: python-2.7, interpolation, missing-data

I have the following vector:

```
x=[1.2, 1.3, 1.4, NaN, 1.6, NaN, NaN, 1.9, 2]   
y=np.isnan(x)   
w=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

How should I call for akima interpolation from scipy?

Comment: thanks @Pedro Lobito